# Use a defined class in main in other files

Tags: c++, function, class

I declared a class I've written in my main file, because I need it there the most. There you see my defined class Sock sock=new Sock();

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#define TEST "test"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

 Sock *sock = new Sock();



int main()
{
    Mat image;
    Mat mbuffer;
    VideoCapture capture;




    uint8_t bytes[11];
```

So now I need this class in another function, witch is in another file to keep the main file clean and easy to read. But I cannot set it public and sock isn't recognized. I just can write a function below my declaration of the class. Is there a way to use a declared class in every file?

Comment: its not really clear if you mean the class `Sock` or the instance `sock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the other files, declare `sock` as follows:

```
extern class Sock *sock;
```

Keyword `extern` tells the compiler that the variable is defined elsewhere.